# Mortgage calculator

Tags: python, date

my aim is to create mortgage calculator in python. I want it to calculate number of days between now, and fixed time in future. To get number od days, or months between two dates I use datetime , that you can see in my code. My problem is that i can't perform division operation on number of days returned by datetime function, because it is in wrong data type. Is there any option to change date type into integer?

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import time


today=datetime.date.today()
d0=date(2021,11,29)
delta=d0-today
print(delta.days)

def diff_month(d1,d2,c1):
    if c1=="monthly":
         a=(d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month
         instalment = 1000000 / a

         return (instalment)
    if c1=="daily":
         a=(d1-d2)
         instalment=1000000/a.days

         return (instalment)




# counter=diff_month(d0,today,"daily")
    #instalment=1000000/counter
    #print(type(counter))
    #print(instalment)
    print(diff_month(d0,today,"daily"))
```

Thanks in advance
edit:
Thanks for your advices, finally i do that in this way. The only problem is that monnthly payment is equal everytime, in reality it would not be equal, because number of days in each month is not constant, so i would rather use daily payment than monthly.

Comment: But you do that correctly in your test before the function: call `.days` on the timedelta object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

On the line:

```
instalment=1000000/counter
```

You expect `counter` to contain the number of days. However, `diff_month` returns the number of months if `c1` is "monthly". Fix this. make the function return the number of days in all cases.

The return value from `diff_month` is of type timedelta. Objects of this type have an attribute called `days` which is an integer, so you can write:

```
instalment=1000000/counter.days
```

Comment: I suggest that instead of writing all your code in the comment, edit the original question and add a section about your changes. Code in the comment is barely readable